# ¿Quiénes somos?

Tags: discusión, faq, usuarios

Spanish Language está creciendo y cada vez somos más usuarios. Algunos indican en su perfil de dónde son y eso nos ayuda a ver que el sitio tiene visitantes de muchos lugares del mundo. A las usuales España, Argentina y Chile, veo de vez en cuando a gente de por ejemplo Paraguay ([josego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14637/josego)).

¿Qué os parece si vamos documentándolo para tener una visión más clara de qué lugares abarcamos y saber a quién consultar en caso de necesitar respuestas con acento particular?

Añado una respuesta en modo wiki de comunidad con mi nombre de usuario y el ámbito del español que conozco y en el que más puedo aportar. Os animo a editarla para incluir la vuestra.

Después, puedes revisar [¡Ayuda a completar las respuestas que varían según la región!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2652/1674) para seguir jugando con este "fill in the gaps" geográfico y lingüístico :)

Comment: Just curious, Fedorqui, what is your current status?  I'm not asking because I think you should or shouldn't do this or that.  I'm just wondering whether you are wearing your moderator hat at present, or maybe I should say, to what degree.

Comment: I am still marked as _absent_ and so will I until I see some progress on Monica's issue. Also, I am a big fan of Spanish.SE and it is hard for me not to step in on moderation duties. So many years doing it, I guess

Comment: Yes, I see.  Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

| **Argentina** |  |
| --- | --- |
| [pablodf76](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14627/pablodf76) | Nacido, criado y viviendo en [Rosario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosario_(ciudad_de_Argentina)), provincia de Santa Fe, región litoral de Argentina, 300 km antes de que el río Paraná se vuelque al océano. Dialecto rioplatense con eses tan aspiradas que ya ni aliento les queda. Digo *poroto*, *pimiento*, *choclo*, *pororó*, *costeleta* y *praliné*. Hablo inglés, portugués brasileño, cachitos de japonés y de alemán. |
| [Lobo-Eze](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11037/lobo-eze) | Oriundo de la [ciudad de Resistencia, provincia del Chaco](https://www.google.com.ar/maps/place/Resistencia,+Chaco/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x94450c62a6f5f70b:0xf03ac86511c2cd6d?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj10OjSg8nWAhVII5AKHYb1CywQ8gEIgAEwDw). Mi dialecto es el rioplatense también, acpa abunda el yeísmo, sin embargo tenemos una tonada y un glosario de palabras propias del Noreste Argentino. Acá se mezcla la forma de hablar del argentino y el paraguayo. Soy estudiante de magisterio (referente a la docencia), y me fascina mi idioma, y estoy aprendiendo mucho leyendolos. En donde pueda brindar mi ayuda la doy. |
| [Gustavson](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14676/gustavson?tab=profile) | Vivo en el Gran Buenos Aires. Soy traductor y me encanta enseñar. Hablo español rioplatense, inglés y portugués, y sé algo de italiano y francés. Trabajo en una empresa de energía pero lo que más me apasiona son las clases (actualmente soy profesor de traducción jurídico-administrativa y económico-financiera en [una institución de estudios superiores de Buenos Aires](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instituto_de_Ense%C3%B1anza_Superior_en_Lenguas_Vivas_Juan_Ram%C3%B3n_Fern%C3%A1ndez)). |
| **Brasil** |  |
| [Alan Evangelista](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22797/alan-evangelista) | Nací en Rio de Janeiro y vivo actualmente en Campinas, en el departamento de São Paulo, en el sureste de Brasil. Soy ingeniero de software y a veces profesor de inglés en mi tiempo libre. Hablo portugués brasileño, inglés, francés, alemán, italiano y un poco de japonés. Actualmente estoy estudiando ruso. |
| **Chile** |  |
| [Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/6915/rodrigo) | Soy de Santiago, pero desde hace 20 años resido en la Araucanía, en la zona sur del país. |
| [vladimir-nul](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13136/vladimir-nul) | También Santiaguino. Desde hace un tiempo vivo en Finlandia con mi mujer y mis hijas. Soy ingeniero de software, hablo inglés y alemán fluidos. Estudié polaco dos semestres (mientras vivía en Alemania), y actualmente estoy aprendiendo finlandés. |
| **Colombia** |  |
| [Diego Galeano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/11102/dgaleano) | Nacido en las montañas de Colombia en la [*ciudad de la eterna primavera*](http://www.colombia.travel/en/where-to-go/andean/medellin) |
| [Mauricio Martínez J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5440828/mauricio-mart%C3%ADnez-jim%C3%A9nez) | Ingeniero de software (de "sistemas", realmente, pero no sé si en toda parte se entienda). Trabajo como programador y me gusta la ortografía y el buen uso del español. Así que en lugar de resistirme al querer corregir la ortografía de mis conocidos, aprovecho para ver que puedo aportar por acá, además de aprender del resto. Aprendo inglés y alemán. |
| **Cuba** |  |
| [Theia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17076/theia?tab=profile) | Mi nombre es David. Soy de Holguin. Estudio Ingenieria en Informaticas 2do año. Me apaciona la programacion y estoy aprendiendo ingles. No me dedico a estudiar español pero si me preocupa usar cada palabra como se debe, y evito usar una sin saber que significa exactamente, para eso me auxilio de este sitio. |
| **España** |  |
| [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui) | zona nordeste de España. También hablo catalán. |
| [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/carlos-alejo) | [Sevilla](https://www.google.es/maps/place/Sevilla). Mi nombre real es Carlos Alejo, y también hablo andaluz (¿no cuela?). Bueno, pues inglés y algo de italiano y japonés. |
| [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego) | Nací y crecí en Madrid, pero actualmente resido en Cambridge, Massachusetts (EEUU). |
| [Alicia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17759/alicia) | Nacida y actualmente residiendo en Galicia, la tierra de las [meigas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiga), aunque pasé tres años en La Mancha que me ayudaron a "neutralizar" mi castellano. Soy oficialmente ingeniera de software, y, no oficionalmente, apasionada de las mates, la música y las lenguas. Además de español y gallego nativos, hablo con cierta decencia inglés (por suerte) y francés (por desgracia). |
| [JLPrieto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/18789/jlprieto) | Madrileño de Chamberí (ahí es nada, lo siento por vosotros). Soy un viejo informático, llevo 45 años tocando ordenadores y lidiando con el idioma anglosajón, tan es así que desde los años 80 llevo reuniendo [terminología informática](http://www.tugurium.com/gti) y en 2003 decidí montar una base datos y vía web ponerla a disposición de quien quisiera venir. |
| [Gorpik](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1768/gorpik) | Nací en Aragón, al nordeste de España, pero llevo veinte años viviendo en Madrid. Fui uno de los primeros usuarios de [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (sí, otro que se dedica a la informática). Como me gustan mucho las lenguas, me uní al foro de [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) al poco de abrirse y luego aquí. También hablo portugués, aunque cada vez menos porque, desgraciadamente, lo uso poco. |
| [wimi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/24236/wimi) | nací y viví en el norte de España, después me mudé a Alemania. También hablo inglés, alemán e italiano. |
| **Estados Unidos** |  |
| [Lambie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/19182/lambie) | Nací y fui criada en Rio de Janeiro (tengo doble nacionalidad, Brasil y EEUU). Soy intérprete (español, francés y portugués<>inglés). Hice la escuela de traducción de la Sorbonne (ESIT). No hago traducciones escritas hacia el español. Estoy casada con un sevillano y vivo en el estado de Massachusetts. Aprendi español viajando por España y quedándome a ratos por ahí, con mi marido y con muchos hablantes latino americanos - exilados y otros - en Paris (argentinos, uruguayos, chilenos, dominicanos y puertoriquennos). ¡Y con telenovelas mexicanas! :) |
| **México** |  |
| [hlecuanda](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14033/hlecuanda) | Nací en Guadalajara Jalisco, Crecí en Baja California, viví en Los Angeles, California y una temporada demasiado corta en Barcelona. Bilingüe a nivel nativo; Ingeniero Mecánico por preparación académica, en realidad soy *computodólogo* y por las noches, rockstar de medio tiempo. n.n actualmente resido en [Ensenada](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ensenada,+Baja+California,+Mexico/@31.8423287,-116.6099119,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80d88ef01f54b9f5:0xf360981bb676a651!8m2!3d31.8667427!4d-116.5963713) y como decimos en esta región: ¡Arriba el *norti!, i'ñor*. Y el que lo dude... que *mire* el mapa! |
| [aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/9385/aparente001?tab=profile) | Nací en EEUU. Aprendí el español en México, en una ciudad provincial que en aquel entonces tenía muy pocos extranjeros. Actualmente vivo en EEUU, en el estado (pero no la ciudad) de Nueva York. |
| [Krauss](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12572/krauss) | Nací en Baja California Sur pero he vivido en múltiples partes dentro y fuera de México. He tenido la fortuna de recorrer América pero mi lugar preferido es Uruguay. Me considero, mas bien, bilingue (español mexicano e inglés) pero puedo entender (muy pocas) cosas en portugués brasileño, japonés, francés y árabe. Me gustan el mole, el ceviche, el churrasco brasileño, las empanadas argentinas, el vino de Baja California y de Chile, los mates uruguayos y los jamones de España. |
| **Reino Unido** |  |
| [mdewey](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12155/mdewey) | Nacido, criado y viviendo en Inglaterra. Hablo tambien francés y alemán. Trabajo como estadístico. |