# ¿Cuál es el buen uso de las preguntas "autorrespondidas"?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuestas-wiki

En los distintos *Stacks* uno puede responderse sus propias preguntas. Puede suceder que yo haga una pregunta y al cabo del tiempo me la responda a mí mismo (bien porque no había respuestas o porque ninguna de las respuestas me convencía).

En otras ocasiones sé la respuesta en el momento de hacer la pregunta. Es algo que la filosofía de Stack Exchange incluso promueve para crear más contenido de valor en el sitio. Por ejemplo, me he peleado un buen rato para solucionar mi propia duda con un proyecto personal en Javascript (o lo que sea) y quiero ponerlo en el *stack* apropiado para el siguiente que venga.

Creo que incluso el "procedimiento" para este tipo de preguntas autorrespondidas ha ido cambiando con el tiempo, porque si bien es cierto que yo puedo poner mi propia pregunta y respuesta, en un principio se aconsejaba (pero en ningún caso se requería) que pregunta y respuesta afueran marcadas como "community wiki". Más tarde, parece ser que desapareció la posibilidad de poner una pregunta como "community wiki".

Me hago esta pregunta porque más de una vez que me preguntado cosas como "cuál es el origen de esta expresión" (un tipo de pregunta que hace como un año y medio no veía casi por el foro y que ahora veo mucho, y es el tipo de pregunta-curiosidad que me encanta). Para muchas de ellas me bastó una búsqueda rápida en Google para encontrar una respuesta fiable. La duda viene en si aportaría valor ponerlas entonces en Spanish.SE, ya que por un lado no eran preguntas muy complicadas de resolver invirtiendo un poco de tiempo en buscar por internet, pero por el otro se facilita contenido a los usuarios de este sitio. Aparte no querría que esta práctica evolucionase en un mal uso, degradando la calidad del contenido del sitio.

Por otro lado, podría darse la posibilidad de que otros usuarios aportasen respuestas alternativas o incluso completasen o ampliasen [respuestas que dependen de la zona](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2586/5481). Posiblemente no le sacamos tanto partido a las "diferencias regionales" como podríamos.

Donde digo preguntas tipo "el origen de esta expresión" se puede sugerir por supuesto cualquier otro tipo de pregunta (básicamente un "tenía una duda de gramática y me la resolví yo mismo").

¿Cuál es el buen uso o sus aceptable de preguntas autorrespondidas en este sitio?

---

**Nota:** si hace falta podemos hacer el experimento de pensar tres preguntas distintas y publicarlas con su respuesta para ver cómo responde la comunidad.

Comment: Así a vuelapluma, a mí me parece que [añadir preguntas como referencia](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2457/1674) es buena idea, siempre y cuando sea contenido útil y no trivial (es decir, una expresión algo compleja sí, pero una definición no). Si uno va a autorresponderse, creo importante añadir la respuesta a la vez que se publica la pregunta, para no crear confusión. Que luego otro usuario publique otra respuesta sería fantástico y seguro que añadiría valor. Veamos qué opina la gente, está en nuestras manos decidir cómo lo tratamos.

Comment: Yo tengo publicadas en [Spanish.SE] varias preguntas que me las respondí yo mismo al momento de hacerlas. Normalmente la acogida fue buena, tanto la pregunta como las respuestas fueron bien valoradas y normalmente siempre aparecía algún comentario dando más información. También me ha pasado que yo mismo he publicado la respuesta más tarde, cuando he tenido tiempo de ponerme a responderla (a veces en el mismo día, a veces a partir del día siguiente).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, yo también tengo alguna que me he "autorrespondido" más tarde o más temprano, pero nunca he puesto una en el sentido de ver algo y decir "Esto puede ser interesante para Spanish.SE" y traerlo aquí. Por eso un poco la reflexión de dónde poner "el listón" para esas preguntas. Pero me estoy dando cuenta de que va a ser más bien juzgar pregunta a pregunta que una regla general...