# ¡Ayuda a completar las respuestas que varían según la región!

Tags: discusión, respuestas, respuestas-wiki

En el sitio primamos las preguntas específicas para evitar caer en una serie de respuestas igualmente válidas del tipo "en mi zona lo llamamos X".
Sin embargo, la riqueza del español, sus dialectos y peculiaridades locales, se refleja en Spanish Stack Exchange y es algo que nos hace bien como comunidad.
Vemos con frecuencia aportaciones de gente de un país que otros de otro no conocen, y viceversa, con lo que nuestra "base de datos" y nuestros conocimientos personales se enriquecen más y más.

Tenemos bastantes preguntas cuya respuesta depende de la zona, de ahí que en ocasiones apetezca decirle a alguien de ese país: *oye, tú que eres de aqúi o de allá, ¿cómo lo decís en tu zona?* Léase el caso de respuestas del tipo [¿En qué países la palabra “coger” tiene connotaciones sexuales?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/8754/1674).

En [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674) propuse ir juntando estas respuestas para que sean más fáciles de procesar y ampliar. Y está yendo bastante bien, ya tenemos unas cuantas. En alguna ocasión he pedido a algún usuario si quería añadir las acepciones de su país (¡y [funcionó](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/18186/2)!), pero estaba pensando que podríamos organizarnos un poco mejor.

Por ello propongo ir mirando las respuestas que tenemos actualmente en modo "community wiki" para añadir las variantes de las zonas que conocemos.

En *Juntemos en respuestas...* tenéis la lista completa de preguntas, pero aquí os pongo un resumen por si queréis empezar por aquí:

> - [¿Qué significa "sollado"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16914/1674)
> - [How do you say a “shot” referring to alcohol?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16913/1674)
> - [¿Qué es “inventar el hilo negro”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16984/1674)
> - [¿Se usa 'guácala' fuera de México?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17039/1674)
> - [What does the word “pinche” mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17040/1674)
> - [Fireworks en español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17232/1674)
> - [What's the best way to inform a pedestrian or fellow cyclist that I'm about to pass them?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17245/1674)
> - [Definition of 'escuela' and 'colegio'](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17265/1674)
> - [¿En qué paises aplica la acepción anatómica de “pito”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10035/1674)
> - [¿Cómo se dice regionalmente “coquetear”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2344/1674)
> - [Armpit: sobaco vs. axila](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18186/1674)