# ¿Tenemos usuarios de todos los países donde se habla castellano?

Tags: discusión, usuarios

En la pregunta [¿Quiénes somos?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2586/1674) los usuarios más activos hemos ido indicando de qué zona somos. Es una medida interesante para ver eso, quiénes somos y de dónde venimos.

Al hilo de la pregunta de Travel.SE [Have we visited all the countries / territories as a community?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3907/6997) donde van marcando qué países ha visitado cada usuario, se me ocurre que podríamos documentar por aquí si tenemos usuarios [mínimamente activos] de todos los países donde se habla castellano.

Si la idea prospera, incluso nos puede servir para saber a quién recurrir para consultar casos concretos de preguntas sobre una denominación específica en un lugar concreto.

¿Te animas a indicar a qué zona del mundo representas?

Me surge la duda de si es bueno indicar las personas de un lugar u otro sin que ellas mismas lo indiquen. Por más que el perfil de usuario ya está dando esta información, por lo que ya es pública, yo optaría por incluir solamente a aquellas personas que den su consentimiento explícito, por aquello de evitar que alguien se incomode al ver su nombre en la lista.

Answer (score 3):

Listado de países en base al artículo [Distribución geográfica del idioma español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_geogr%C3%A1fica_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol).

Países donde el castellano es oficial.

#### Argentina

#### Bolivia

#### Chile

#### Colombia

- [veaqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17560/veaqui)

#### Costa Rica

#### Cuba

#### Ecuador

#### El Salvador

#### España

- [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui?tab=profile)
- [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie?tab=profile)

#### Guatemala

#### Guinea Ecuatorial

#### Honduras

#### México

- [aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/9385/aparente001?tab=profile)

#### Nicaragua

#### Panamá

#### Paraguay

#### Perú

#### Puerto Rico

#### República Domincana

#### Sahara Occidental

#### Uruguay

#### Venezuela

---

Países donde el castellano no es oficial, pero tiene bastantes hispanohablantes.

#### Andorra

#### Belice

#### Brasil

#### Canadá

#### Estados Unidos

#### Filipinas

#### Francia

#### Gibraltar

#### Israel

#### Italia

#### Marruecos

Comment: Bueno, ¿realmente no hay ningun usuario estadounidense que quiera agregar su nombre a la lista?